# Does PHP configuration via the Windows registry work for CLI?

Tags: php, ini

I am trying to set the include_path specifically for a given script in a given configuration.
[Per Directory Values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.windows) would be ideally suited for the task, so I am trying this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\Per Directory Values\c\phpDevScripts]
"include_path"="c:\\path\\to\\dev\\lib"
```

It doesn’t seem to work for CLI scripts but the docs say nothing about this.

Comment: How do you call the scripts? With commands for async?

Comment: BTW: PHP uses different configs (.ini) for cgi and cli. Did you read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#80831 ?

Comment: @MarkusHofmannn: I run the scripts in c:\phpDevScripts from the command line and I would expect that c:\phpDevScripts\someScript.php gets its setting from the registry.

Comment: The way you set the reg key looks good to me. However, this will only be applied to apache and not the cli (php runs two different versions, mostly fast-cgi and cli). Why don't you try ini_set or set_include_path in your script? Also try "injecting" a custom php.ini containing your desired changes via the command line, e.g. `php -c /path/to/custom/php.ini -f /phpDevScripts/someScript.php`.

Comment: @MarkusHofmannn: I specifically wanted to avoid

- changing the code of the script (which also runs in other environments) or

- copying/editing the system-wide .ini

I might end up doing that though.

Comment: Remeber, an important rule for a successful project is: [**Keep it simple, stupid**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).   [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).

Comment: If you're running the 32-bit version of PHP on a 64-bit version of Windows you might have to insert WOW6432Node into your registry path as in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432\PHP\Per Directory Values\c\phpDevScripts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the "[User Contributed Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#80831)":

> Being able to put php directives in httpd.conf and have them work on a per-directory or per-vitual host basis is just great. Now there's
>   another aspect which might be worth being aware of:
>
> > A php.ini directive put into your apache conf file applies to php when
> >     it runs as an apache module (i.e. in a web page), but NOT when it runs
> >     as CLI (command-line interface).
>
> Such feature that might be unwanted by an unhappy few, but I guess
>   most will find it useful. As far as I'm concerned, I'm really happy
>   that I can use open_basedir in my httpd.conf file, and it restricts
>   the access of web users and sub-admins  of my domain, but it does NOT
>   restrict my own command-line php scripts..

Comment: I noticed that .htaccess (.user.ini) files are not being taken into account by CLI scripts, but it is never said whether Windows Per Directory Values registry values are.